# Firebase getDownloadURL() not updating global variable

Tags: javascript, firebase-storage

I have the following script

```
    let link = ""
    let baseUrl = "Test-Dataset/"
    let imageRef = "2.jpg"

    storage.ref(baseUrl + imageRef).getDownloadURL().then(
      function(url) {
      link = url
      console.log(url)
    }).catch(function(error) {
    });

    console.log(link)
```

My goal is to update the `link` variable with the value of the image's URL after I use the `getDownloadURL()` to return a promise and wait for it to be resolved. The `console.log` function within the .this() is outputting exactly what I need - the link to the image in my firebase storage. However, the `console.log` outside of the function is returning the initial value of `link` before the call to my firebase storage was made, which is just `""`. Why does this happen? Is my solution to make something like the asynchronous function outlined in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53578626/8849802?

Details: I'm using vue and the npm library `firebase`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your console statement runs before the promise resolves. It has nothing to do with Firebase.

This is what happens:

1. The `link` variable is declared with an empty string.
2. A handler function is added to the promise: `.then(function(url) { ... } )`
3. `console.log(link)` outputs the value of `link` which is still an empty string
4. The promise resolves and sets `link` to `url`.

Try to add this at the very end of your code to see the effect more clearly:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(link);
}, 1000);
```

This will output the value of `link` after 1 second. Its value should be the URL you wanted.

To solve the issue, you can use async/await.

```js
const getLink = async (ref) => {
  const url = await storage.ref(ref).getDownloadURL();

  return url;
}

// NB: A function that uses `await` must be `async`
// So, whichever function uses getLink() must be async

function async someFunction() { // Maybe a Vue method?
  const url = await getLink(baseUrl + imageRef);
  console.log(url);
}
```

To add error handling, use a try/catch block:

```js
function async someFunction() {
  try {
    const url = await storage.ref(baseUrl + imageRef).getDownloadURL();
    console.log(url); // This won't run if getting the URL failed
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle the error
  }
}
```